# HTML transient modal window

Tags: javascript, firefox, modal-dialog, firefox-addon, privileges

We have a legacy web application. At various places it opens a window with the help of Privilege Manager on Firefox to get the needed result.
Some of these windows open a Java applet or a PDF document.
The client machines are updating Firefox and Privilege Manager is gone.

What is the easiest way around it? 
The problems are :

1. There must be only one instance of the pop-up at anyone time. This could be done by selecting appropriate window name on `window.open()` call.
2. If the window is opened again (by means of user action), it should not reload but just focus to bring it to the foreground (I have seen I can keep a reference to the window on JavaScript to do that)
3. It basically really must be transient/modal so that the client cannot leave the current page or reload or any other kind of interaction with the parent window (except opening/refocusing the child window) without closing the child window first. I have no idea how to do that.

Do anyone has an idea how to do that?

The client is only Firefox (it works in a special kiosk configuration) on Linux.

I read somewhere that I could somehow write an extension but I am basically clueless about extensions and its API.

**Edit1:**

Example of (simplified) legacy code. Not really sure if all the permissions were required, but this is it: This function opens a window that stays over the parent window and prevents any interaction from the user with the parent window.

```
function fWindowOpen(url, name) {
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserWrite");
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager
            .enablePrivilege("CapabilityPreferencesAccess");
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager
            .enablePrivilege("UniversalPreferencesWrite");
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager
            .enablePrivilege("UniversalPreferencesRead");
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalFileRead");
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
    window.open(
        url,
        name,
        "screenX=70,dependent=yes,menubar=0,toolbar=0,width=900,height=700,modal=1,dialog=1"
        );
}

function fnCapture(){
    fWindowOpen("/path/to/document_or_japplet/page","_blank");                      
}
```

HTML:

```
<button value="Capture" property="btnCapture" onclick="javascript:fnCapture();"/>
```

Edit2: Solution

On a typical extension, on the xul code, define this javascript code:

```
var dialogExt = {
 listener: function(evt) {
  // Do work with parameters read through evt.target.getAttribute("attribute_name")
  window.openDialog(evt.target.getAttribute("url"), evt.target.getAttribute("name"), evt.target.getAttribute("features"));
 }
}
// from examples
document.addEventListener("dialogExtEvent", function(e){ dialogExt.listener(e); }, false, true);
```

Then, on the web page:

```
var element = document.createElement("dialogExtElement");
element.setAttribute("url", url);
element.setAttribute("name", name);
element.setAttribute("features", features);
document.documentElement.appendChild(element);
var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
evt.initEvent("dialogExtEvent", true, false);
element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Now, maybe I am missing some security checks to let the code work if it originates from the same host, and how to handle a reference to the document that requested the dialog as means of interaction between the dialog window and it's opener.

Comment: can you post an example of what the old code was doing? and would auto-close on loss of focus be acceptable for the modal dialog?

Comment: I have added a somewhat simplified example of legacy code. Don't know about auto-close on loss of focus. I guess it could be a hazzle for the user if (s)he has done some work on the child window, but it seems like a viable compromise to me. An actual transient/modal window would be preferable though if I knew how to get it done with an extension and how to interact between the html document/javascript and the extension.

Comment: Do you really **need** the new window to be modal to the *entirety of Firefox*, or just the page you are on/pages you control? If you can live with it being modal just for the page you are on or pages you control, you do not need elevated privileges. If it is just modal for the pages you control, that can be accomplished with normal unprivileged JavaScript.

Comment: How does that work?. The content in the child window is part of the workflow so the parent window must not allow to continue until the child window is closed. A sepparate tab or window that wouldn't interfere would be ok. Currently this is a kiosk setup where starting page is a webapp that does not have any link to the outside. User cannot interact with the browser in any other way (no url bar, menus, tabs, key short-cuts, etc). There is a configuration with two tabs open each displaying two separate sites. A started activity in either site must finish before using the other so would be ok too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Privilege Manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Bypassing_Security_Restrictions_and_Signing_Code) was [deprecated in Firefox 12 and removed in Firefox 17](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/17/Site_compatibility#Security) ([briefly restored](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=791526)).

You might want to look into [`Window.showModalDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog). However, it is deprecated and is expected to go away within the year, or in 2016 if you go with an extended service release (ESR) of Firefox 38. It may be a temporary solution while you develop an extension.

In order to accomplish the same tasks, you will need to write an extension and ask the user to install it (from [Bypassing Security Restrictions and Signing Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Bypassing_Security_Restrictions_and_Signing_Code), the old information about Privilege Manager):

> Sites that require additional permissions should now ask Firefox users to install an [extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions), which can [interact with non-privileged pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages) if needed.

It is possible to write such an extension using any of the three different extension types:

1. [XUL overlay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions)
2. [Restartless/Bootstrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions)
3. [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK)

For the first two types, you would use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). The `modal` option is in ["Features requiring privileges"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Features_requiring_privileges).  You will probably also want to look at [`Window.openDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/openDialog).

For the Add-on SDK, you would normally use the [`open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils#open%28uri.2C_options%29) function in the SDK's [window/utils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils) module. Here, again, you will probably want to look at [`openDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils#openDialog%28options%29).

It appears you may be opening content that is supplied from the web in these modal windows. It is unlikely that you will get an extension approved to be hosted on [AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) which opens content in such windows which in not included in the add-on release.  This does not mean you can not develop the extension and have it installed on your kiosk clients without hosting it on AMO.  However, there are additional restrictions in development for Firefox this year which will make this significantly more difficult, see: ["Introducing Extension Signing: A Safer Add-on Experience"](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/02/10/extension-signing-safer-experience/).

Comment: Thank you. There is no worries about hosting the extension somewhere. It is not going to be used over the internet but inside a private network only. These quioscs come with the browser already configured. But it is good to know. Thank you for the heads up about signing. We have dealed with similar situations with java. I hope it does not become too troublesome.

Comment: Thank you so much. Halfway there. I still need to pass a reference from the window that "opened" the dialog to the child window .

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get similiar `window.open` behavior, including support for the `modal` option from the sdk's [window/utils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils#open%28uri.2C_options%29) module.

You will have to install the onclick listener with a [content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts), send a message to the addon-main through its port and then open that window from the addon main.