# firefox extension opendialog opener null

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have an extension to help it's website open a dialog with content. The child window needs to operate the opener window (reload the parent/opener's content).

And so, the child window tries to execute code like the following:

```
parent.opener.location.reload();parent.close();
```

or

```
parent.opener.document.forms[0].hdReload.value="false";
parent.opener.document.forms[0].submit();
```

How can I let the child window communicate this way with it's parent this way?

As a side note, how do I restrict access so that code loaded from ip X can open a window with content from ip X?

This is in relation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037807/html-transient-modal-window) regarding modal windows.

Edit 1:
Tried this code first inside the add-on

```
window.openDialog(url,name,features,event.target.ownerDocument);
```

And in the child window I could reference the opener window through

```
window.arguments[0];
```

But the child window in turn will load another document, and it looks like the second document loaded in the child window has no window.arguments. 
I guess they are erased when the child window loads another document.

Comment: does it actually have to be "parent.opener" or is any way to communicate with the other window sufficient?

Comment: The example is code that is inside a frame, hence the parent.opener. But it just needs to communicate with the opener window.

Comment: "As a side note [...]" that would seem like a separate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the SDK's [`open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils#open%28uri.2C_options%29) you can pass a parent window, which should then be available to the child as `window.parent` property.

If the windows are on the same domain and thus share session storage you can use [StorageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent)s to let the communicate with each other.
Install event listeners on the window and write to the storage in the other window and they'll be able to pass messages that way and act on each other.

But the IP X/Y thing suggests that they're from separate origins, but if you have control over the network you could fix that by mapping those IPs to a common domain as subdomains and then setting `document.domain` to the base domain to relax the same origin policy.

If neither is an option you might be able to inject one window's window object into the context of another window so they can use [window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), but I think that may fail due to security barriers.

The last option would be to bounce messages this way: Window A <-> Addon <-> Window B. This can be done by having the addon code use `.postMessage` to send data to the window itself and then the window replies by sending another message to itself for which the addon has installed a privileged event listener. If you're using the SDK you'll also have to bounce that through the port API, so there will be several layers of indirection involved.

Comment: The window is created with openDialog from a xul file. Not using the sdk as a do not know if I could define the event listener there. It is a dialogWindow as it needs to be modal. all documents belong to the same website app, the side question was just avoid a script from another domain to request a change to the opener window if that situation ever happened, but yes it could be a different question.

Comment: Are the storage events privileged functions that are required to be used inside the addon or can I use them from the webpage/document code? I suspect it is the second case because as you said they require to share session storage.

Comment: they are not privileged

Comment: I don't quite get the use of initStorageEvent. I have browsed a little and have found localStorage with it's three methods getItem,setItem and removeItem to trigger a 'storage' event wich can be handled with an event listener (downside is I must take care of cleaning the keys). What is the use of initStorageEvent then? If I could have kept a reference to the document accross links on the child window would have been easier as would have meant less new code.

Comment: Got it now. Creating, initializing and dispatching the event lets me do it regardless if there was an actual change in the value of a storage element. Not sure about the url parameter effect, Does it mean that only a document with that url  can catch the event? or is it left to the listener to deside if it processes the event based on the url?

Comment: I didn't actually mean to suggest using `initStorageEvent`, but using synthetic events to talk to content is another approach, yes.